# 3rd Party SMS Vendor for Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Just wondering if anyone here have experience integrating a 3rd party sms provider into marketing cloud instead of using salesforce's code.

I'm looking at this option due to the exorbitant super messages cost of sending an sms with SFMC.

Any comments and insights would be helpful!

Comment: MobileConnect will only work with SF provided short/long codes. Anything custom means you'll be using 3rd party tool API to recieve information from Marketing Cloud, ie mobile number, SMS content.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this in Marketing Cloud would be by creating a [custom Journey Builder activity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm).

You need a Javascript and server-side technology developers (PHP, Java, NodeJS, etc.) to create a service of which the user interface would be displayed in a Journey Builder window when you click the corresponding activity. Journey Builder would send a payload of data to your service and it would need to pass it along to the API endpoint of your 3rd party SMS provider of choice.

Comment: Thank you. We are proceeding with this integration.